# Node.js node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 error while trying to use discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with the command prefix "*" but when I try to get the bot online/run it, it gives me this error:

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\name\const'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

The module I'm using is discord.js and i've installed discord.js on CMD and the VSC terminal but it still comes up with the MODULE NOT FOUND error. I've looked around the internet and I can't find one that fixes the problem. I've tried reinstalling Node.js but it won't stop coming back.

Comment: How are you running your bot? Are you in the correct directory?

Comment: did you installed it with `npm install` ??

Comment: @ME-ON1 I installed discord.js with "npm install discord.js"

Comment: show your `package.json` in the directory where you running `node index.js`.

Comment: @lejlun I'm running my bot in VSC with node index.js. I just went to the directory and it gives me another error "TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client."

Comment: @ME-ON1 package.json "{
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.0.1"
  }
}

Answer (score 14):

same error with me but I just change file dir cause I run `node <filename.js>` in the wrong dir so I just change like ---
the first step chacks you are in the right dir or not **type:** > `ls`
then if you are in the right dir then **type:** `node <filename.js>` if not then change your dir to change dir **type:** `cd <filename>`
and then run your first app or file for run **type:**  `node <filename.js>`

I hope your error is solved!

Answer (score 6):

you need to run it as an administrator so sudo(whatever you tryna run) as long as you are in the right directory

Answer (score 4):

On Windows I solved it like this.

I went to the folder: C:\Users\Documents\AppData\Roaming\npm

And I deleted the file. create-react-app.

I started the project again, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

root cause, my path was messed up, but I only figured that out once I found where my npm packages where. I had thought they were in ../Programs/Roaming/npm etc but since an update (I think to node) my packages were actually in a Python Lib subdir.

Your Answer might be the same as mine, and I found out all this by using the

```
npm list -g
```

Command - which showed the globally installed packages, but also highlighted that this was nowhere to be found in my path

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and it was a case of trying to run the file in node from the wrong location.

My solution was to use the terminal and CD into the exact folder the file I was trying to run were and then after that I could run `node filename.js`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (this error ocurred at running docker container of next app), it was because I was running docker-compose without the flag `--build`, but of without copy lock files (package-lock.json and/or yarn.lock).

I updated my Dockerfile:

```
[...]

COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile 
CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

And after, run with `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 1):

When I was following a JS tutorial i got this error message too.
The problem was I copied an existing JS file and renamed it but it
through that error when i ran it.
When i created a new JS file, and copied the code in, and ran, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting your server you need to make sure that the start file is mentioned  below

cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index`<start file name eg:index for index.js>`

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you run `npm run start` without getting into the project first... So, before starting to compile your project, run this command: `cd <project folder name>`...

It will stop showing the "Missing Module" Error and smoothly run your desired output in your browser

Answer (score 1):

**When was trying to find 'npm' & 'Rdme' path from command prompt to update the Rdme was getting this error Log**

This error is caused when file can't be found or its a wrong path, In my case I added the missing file to respective folders- configured & updated  in **Environment variables** (after adding missing files)

Answer (score 1):

For the coming next. For me I'v got the error when I tried to run a package.json script with the npx run rather npm run.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to install nodejs and it fixed my issue.

Open an Administrator Command Prompt (right click Command Prompt and select "Run as Administrator"), then run the following command:

```
choco install -y nodejs-lts
```

I hope it works for you too :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case path was giving an issue as per folder structure.
I had

```
"main": "app.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon app.js"
},
```

I changed it to

```
"main": "app.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon src/app.js"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that you've required packages that you haven't installed. So please make sure that you've installed every package that you've required in your bot. Also if you're sure that you've installed it, please check it again, there were namely some problems for some people that some of their packages got uninstalled while updating Discord.js to version 13.

For your problem in the comments ("TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]"), it is now required in Discord.js version 13 to add your needed intents in the client. Please read [this](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#intents) part of the Discord.js guide.

Comment: I restarted the bot project and this time I turned the intents on for the bot and code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the opened directory of the terminal. Just go to the terminal and type: `cd <folder name>` until you reach the folder in which your js file is located. Then save and run again.

Answer (score -1):

npm uninstall webpack-cli -D

npm install webpack-cli@3.3.12 --save-dev

than work fine