# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942 throw err;

Tags: node.js, solidity, vscode-debugger

I am trying to run some solidity code but receiving this error on vs code. I am not sure what the issue is.

> node version
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
> throw err;
> ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/h/U_Block Developer/star/version'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

I am on Mac Monterey OS.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZMST.png)

Comment: please have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692968/node-js-nodeinternal-modules-cjs-loader936-error-while-trying-to-use-discord-j?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing some modules from the repo. If you're using node, you can run `node install` on the root file. If you're using yarn, then `yarn install`.

Comment: Hi @zi Thanks for the response. I did do the node install but it didn't work. The weirdest part the code was running fine then all of a sudden it stopped working. I see this little debug symbol appear in package.json file.  >node version  or > node -v doesn't work. I added a screenshot on the top link.

Comment: The debug get added to all the node code file even if I open a new node package from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I found some things to say in this case, i was trying to execute `'npm install'` and appear this error, one thing that I notice was the route that show for launch the js file, but it was estrange, it was this:

```
'C:\Users\Owner\anaconda3\Library\c\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

and it was that i was trying execute the command with conda activated, so I had to deactivate conda, with this simple command `'conda deactivate'`.
Next launch me an error where don't found the file `package.json`, so I had to change the name of `'package-lock.json'` to `'package.json'` and with this I achieve execute `'npm install'` successfully.

Answer (score -3):

So recently i just came up with the similiar problem which initially got solved my repairing nodejs through the installer , it's in your C drive probably, just repair it and you are good to go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).