# Cannot find module 'internal/modules/cjs/loader :1093

Tags: javascript, node.js, notepad++, node-modules, nppexec

After running the Java script code in Notepad++, I am facing  the following error. How to solve it?

```
NPP_EXEC: "node"
CD: $ (CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
Current directory: E:\
node $ (FILE_NAME)
Process started (PID=4064) >>>
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\$'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 error while trying to use discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692968/node-js-nodeinternal-modules-cjs-loader936-error-while-trying-to-use-discord-j)